# Use StreamWriter() to write to the same file as StreamReader()

Tags: powershell

I want to find and replace a certain string in a number of files. Some of these files can be relatively large so I am using the `StreamReader` class from the `System.IO` namespace.

The issue I have is that I don't want to have to write the new values to a new file (which is what I have currently). I want to just "update" the current files.

```
$currentValue = "B";
$newValue = "A";

# Loop through all of the directories and update with new details. 
foreach ($file in $Directories) {
    $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "$file"
    $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$file"
    # Switching $streamWriter to the below works.
    # $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\Temp\newFile.txt"

    while($line = $streamReader.ReadLine()){
        # Write-Output "Current line value is $line";
        $s = $line -replace "$currentValue", "$newValue"
        # Write-Output "The new line value is $s"
        $streamWriter.WriteLine($s);
    }

    # Close the streams ready for the next loop.
    $streamReader.close();
    $streamWriter.close();
}

Write-Output "The task has complete."
```

Does anyone know how I could go about doing the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't read and write from/to the same file simultaneously. Not with `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, nor with any other usual method. If you need to modify an existing file and can't (or don't want to) read its entire content into memory you *must* write the modified content to a temporary file and then replace the original with the temp file after both files were closed.

Example:

```
$filename = (Get-Item $file).Name

$streamReader = New-Object IO.StreamReader -Arg $file
$streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "$file.tmp"

...

$streamReader.Close(); $streamReader.Dispose()
$streamWriter.Close(); $streamWriter.Dispose()

Remove-Item $file -Force
Rename-Item "$file.tmp" -NewName $filename
```

Comment: Ok that is what I expected but wanted to be sure. Thanks for you help Ansgar.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( $my_infile.Length -gt 0 ) {
  [string] $full_name_infile = $my_dir + "\" + $my_infile
  $f1 = Get-Content($full_name_infile) -ErrorAction Stop
  if ( $f1.count -gt 0 ) { 
       [string] $fout1_dir = $my_dir 
       [string] $fout1_name = $fout1_dir + "\"  + $my_infile + ".temp"
       $fmode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Append
       $faccess = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write
       $fshare = [System.IO.FileShare]::None
       $fencode = [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII
       $stream1 = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $fout1_name, $fmode, $faccess, $fshare
       $fout1 = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream1, $fencode
  }

  for ( $x=0; $x -lt $f1.count; $x++ ) {
    $line = $f1.Get( $x )
    if ( $line.length -eq 0 ) {
       $nop=1
    } else {
         if (  $line.Substring( $line.Length-1 , 1 ) -eq "," ) { $line = $line + " "; }
         $fout1.WriteLine( $line );
    }

  }
  $fout1.Close()
  $fout1.Dispose()
  move-item  $fout1_name $full_name_infile -force 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.