# Modifying a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file and I want to replace the headers in A1, B1, C1. Then delete the entire D1 column.

The three header names look like

```
A1 = PM #
B1 = AssignGroup
C1 = Status
```

I want to rename them to

```
A1 = VStatus
B1 = Solution_Date
C1 = Ticket_Number
```

The file name is `Owner.csv`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for things like this.

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\owner.csv'
(Import-Csv $csv) |
    Select-Object @{n='VStatus';e={$_.'PM #'}},
                  @{n='Solution_Date';e={$_.AssignGroup}},
                  @{n='Ticket_Number';e={$_.Status}} |
    Export-Csv $csv -NoType
```

Note that you need to run `Import-Csv` in an expression, so that reading the file is completed before `Export-Csv` starts writing to it.

Comment: This man is a speed machine, answered within 5 mins of the question being asked!

Comment: I just happened to see the question shortly after it was posted, and it's a rather basic question anyway. There are faster guns in the West than me.

Comment: lol, *basic*. I understand everything about your solution but I'm still long way of writing that on top of my head.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - If Import-Csv must be in an expression to complete before Export-Csv runs, then I take it that this would not be suitable for a large (more than the amount of physical memory) file. Is that true?

Comment: @lit That's correct. Running `Import-Csv` in a (sub)expression (or assigning its output to a variable) would read the entire file into memory.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Reading and writing an entire file just to change one line is a lot of overhead. Powershell doesn't have a more optimal way to do this?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers It's the most convenient way, because you don't need to worry about column order, etc. There are [approaches with better performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34854843/1630171), but they require more code, and you'd still need to read and write the entire file (since you [don't really edit any file in-place](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/)), even if you could pass most of the content without looking at it. Which you can't, because the OP wants to remove one column from the file in addition to changing the headers.