# How to performantly edit only first line of file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to go over 10,000 files and only do modifications on the first line.

It seems to me that when I do `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` it really does go over the whole file so that takes way longer than I would like.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently in Powershell?

Comment: You can speed up processing by using [`StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34854843/1630171), but as far as I'm aware you cannot edit a file "in-place". You must read the full content, modify it, then write it back.

Comment: Reading this [Is there a way to edit a file on a HDD formatted using NTFS, directly, in-place](https://superuser.com/a/1151845/6825), it looks like NTFS allows inplace editing as long as the size doesn't change.  For OP this likely means there's no way around but reading the entire file.

Comment: Can you detail the "modifications" you'd like to make? The implication of @LievenKeersmaekers' comment is that the offset for line 2 must be the same, so unless you're replacing individual characters 1-to-1, you can only remove content and then right-pad with whitespace, but not add anything

Comment: They wouldn't be the same. I wan't to add a few characters to the first line depending on the content of the first line